# How to convert mutiple dataframes in a list to xts object

Tags: r, dataframe, xts

I have a list that list consisting of 1000 data frames each data frame having first column as Date. I want to convert all these data frames into xts object.

I have converted date into Date object using lapply.

I want to convert every data frame to xts in one command not individually one by one as it will take much time.

Comment: Please include your efforts in the question. This is not a code writing service, it is a platform to solve specific issues.

Comment: @ Harshal Parekh sorry for that. I first time use this site. Therefore I do not know about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to loop over the `list`, remove the first column which is the 'Date', apply the `xts` and specify the `order.by` as the first column (assuming that the class of 'Date' column is `Date`)

```
library(xts)
lst2 <- lapply(lst1, function(x) xts(x[-1], order.by = x[,1]))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
lst1 <- list(data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date('2015-01-01'), 
  length.out = 10, by = '1 day'), Col2 = rnorm(10)),
     data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date('2017-01-01'), 
   length.out = 10, by = '1 day'), Col2 = rnorm(10)))
```

Comment: @ akrun awesome it worked. But why we delete first column first I am confused